# how to sync Local SQLite database to server when update in table

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, synchronization

i am adding many items...but not provide any user login when an user added 3 or 4  item in sqlite table when user uninstall application and again install application ,he should get whatever item he added into table

Answer (score 1):

Google syncadapter and maintain your database on server according to the users,you can sync local database on mobile and on server using this,use these links:-

http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html
http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/

Comment: for user i must provide login..data should vary for different user

Comment: yes that is the part you have to take care of,and please upvote my answer if it helped you